# How to hide fields with angular in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, field

I have the form with fields (name, tel, email, etc.)

```
<ion-content>
      <div class="list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col" ng-hide="hideFild" id="nom">
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
              <span class="input-label">Nom</span>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Nom" ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="30" name="nom" ng-model="noteForm.nom">
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
              <span class="input-label">Prenom</span>
              <input type="text" ng-maxlength="20" placeholder="Prenom"  ng-model="noteForm.prenom">
            </label>
          </div> ...
```

And I have another page where I control the visibility of fields:

```
template.html
<ion-view view-title=" Paramétrage formulaire">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-repeat="fild in filds" class="item item-toggle">
                    {{fild.name}}
                    <label class="toggle toggle-balanced">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fild.value" ng-change="change(fild)">
                        <div class="track">
                            <div class="handle"></div>
                        </div>
                    </label>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

with `controller.js` for save a data in local storage.

Result in local storage:
[image]

Result $scope.noteForm:
[image]

How to hide form fields that have the value false in local storage?
Thank you all!!!

Comment: Hi, did you try getting localStorage values in controller and write `*ngIf="valueFromStorage"` on html div tag of each field?

Comment: Thanks @DjezzzL I got it:

`function hideFilds() {
            var getfields = SettingsFormService.getObject('filds');
            for (var key in getfields) {
                if (!getfields.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                var obj = getfields[key];
                for (var prop in obj) {
                    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
                    if (prop == 'value') {
                        var value = obj[prop];
                    }
                    $scope['hide' + key] = value;
                }
            }
        }`